# cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explict Conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#

can any one here help me fix this pls

```
object[] parametersObjects = new object[]
            {
                this.Client,
                string.Concat(new string[]
                {
                    Class15.NiQuukmat3,
                    Data.SPL_SOCKET,
                    "msg:",
                    text,
                    Data.SPL_SOCKET,
                    array[0],
                    Data.SPL_SOCKET,
                    array[1],
                    Data.SPL_SOCKET,
                    Class15.lGiu4xuk4E,
                    Data.SPL_SOCKET,
                    "0",
                    Data.SPL_SOCKET,
                    "0",
                    Data.SPL_SOCKET,
                    Data.SPL_ARRAY,
                    Data.SPL_SOCKET,
                    this.classClient.ClientRemoteAddress
                }),
                Class5.Encoding().GetBytes("null"),
                this.classClient
            };
```

give me error at `Class15.NiQuukmat3,` and `Class15.lGiu4xuk4E,`

error : cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explict Conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

please any one here can help me fix this problem ?

`Class15.NiQuukmat3 = "2";` and `Class15.lGiu4xuk4E = "ddll";`

Comment: So...what's the data type of `Class15.NiQuukmat3` and `Class15.lGiu4xuk4E`? Something that's not a `string`, perhaps?

Comment: If this code worked the way you expected, what would be populated in the second element of `parametersObjects`? Do you want a string? If so, what text specifically do you want the string to contain?

Comment: ` Class15.NiQuukmat3 = "2"; ` and ` Class15.lGiu4xuk4E = "ddll"; `

Comment: Please post a [mre]. What you have in the post and your comment doesn't line up with the error you say you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

First, your post lacks more info regarding the issue, especially the types of the failed classes u mentioned.

Without that, you can try to use either `ToString()` or cast `(string)Class15.NiQuukmat3`.

If its some kind of a class you could try serializinF it using `JsonConvert.Serialize(Class15.NiQuukmat3)` from newtonsoft json package.

If you want particular help, you would have to share more data.

Comment: If you need the author to provide more information to get a better answer, make a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You can do both

Comment: Ok, so do that. Post a comment asking for more details, and then, _once you have enough info_, make an answer.

Comment: thanks bro , thanks all i managed to fix it.